# how to use pip module to list versions on a server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to figure out how to use pip as a module. Specifically, I want to be able to query a local pypi server for available module version numbers.

I've learned, for example, I can do this to get a list of packages installed on my machine:

```
import pip
for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    print dist.key, dist.version
```

I want the equivalent, but for getting packages available on my own pypi server. Is there a good way to do that, or is pip not really designed to be used by anything other than the pip command line utility?

Ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is to build in auto-update functionality to a program I'm writing, so I need to be able to get the version I have and the version that's available.

I'm looking for a solution for python 2.7.

Comment: pip by itself runs locally. How are you planning to communicate with your server?

Comment: @Rod: Ah, I see my question wasn't very clear. When I said "server" I meant my own pypi server running on another machine. From the command line I would do something like `pip ... -i http://my_server:8080/simple ...`, but I want to do that using pip as a module rather than exec'ing the pip command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line `pip list -o` to [list the outdated packages](http://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/4/26/pip-list-outdated/).

If you want to use it as a module, you have to replicate what pip is doing since it is expecting to be used from the command line. The following function will output a list of tuples ('package', 'current version', 'latest version') assuming that you only want to look on your local server

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys
import re

from pip import parseopts
from pip.commands import commands

def list_outdated(pypi_server):
    args = ['list', '-o', '-f', pypi_server, '--no-index']
    cmd_name, options, args, parser = parseopts(args)
    command = commands['list'](parser)

    _stdout = sys.stdout
    output = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = output
    command.main(args, options)
    sys.stdout = _stdout

    return re.findall('(\w+)\s+\(Current:\s+(.*?) Latest:\s+(.*?)\)', output.read() * 2)

outdated = list_outdated('http://my_server:8080/packages/')
```

Comment: hmmm. interesting, though I'm not a big fan of tricking the module into thinking it's running a command line tool. I was hoping the pip module was a bit more re-usable than that :-\ Thanks, though.